# How to store shopping cart items by unique ID in $_SESSIONS?

Tags: php

I am developing a Shopping cart application and I am needing help about storing cart items using $_SESSION.

**The Concept**

When user clicks on Add to Cart, the following information is stored: Product ID e.g. 5312, Product Name, Product Quantity, Product Rules (e.g. color : white, size : medium and so on)

**The problem**

The problem is that when I save the entry in $_SESSION by item ID. I want to assume the following:

- User adds 1 item of product #11 which color is white
- User then adds 2    items of product #11 which color is blue

If I save by item ID, the info will be overridden always, I want to make each call / each add to cart unique because I am assuming he may add different sizes, different colors of the same product.

How can I come over such a problem?

Any ideas or inputs are greatly appreciated.

Comment: you don't want to store the order in a session, store it in a db, with a reference to the session and the user. However $_SESSION[]=$product_array; should work

Comment: You mean $_SESSION[] would be unique each time?

Comment: yes the [] will increment the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a multidimensional array with your SESSION variable.

```
$_SESSION['cart']=array(
    $product_id=>array($product_count,$product_options),
    $product_id=>array($product_count,$product_options),
);
```

Or if the `$product_id` isn't unique:

```
$_SESSION['cart']=array(
    array($product_id,$product_count,$product_options),
    array($product_id,$product_count,$product_options),
);
```

With something like this, you can have a unique product id as the array key, then store the count, options, and other info you need.

Another option would be to create a table for your shopping cart, and then have the session store the cart ID.  Then you would simply check the mysql table for your cart info.

Answer (score 0):

You can store an array using the product ID as a key.

Comment: But that would duplicate the product ID if he added the same product but with different color/size/etc, no?

Comment: No it wouldn't, the key is the product ID, and it contains an array with the products.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing a product in session store a cart item object.  Cart item object would have a reference to the product (product ID) along with any attributes for that item (color, quantity, different price if necessary etc.).  Assign a random ID to each cart item and you never run into a problem of overriding.